# How do I have Ninject execute a factory I define to create my object?

Tags: ninject

Can I have Ninject execute a factory I define in order to create, say, object `B` below?

One way I can think of is by changing Foo's API like so:

```
class Foo
{
  public Foo(Bar b) { }

  // change API to introduce a new ctor
  [Inject]
  public Foo(Func<Bar> func) { }
}

class Bar { }
```

Is there an API in-built in Ninject 3.2 that will let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Bind<Bar>().ToMethod(ctx => ... your factory code/call...);
```

and then just inject a `Bar` into foo:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(Bar b) { }
}
```

---

If you need to control the time when to create the `Bar` - so if your code needs to call the factory specifically - you can use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory). Inject a `Func<Bar> barFactory` into your `Foo` and use it to create an instance.